# How to change the background color in kableExtra?

Tags: r, background-color, kableextra

Looking for a way to set the background color.
I know how to change single elements but couldn't figure it out how to do it for the whole html document.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The question is unclear: do you want to alter "the whole html document", or just the tables generated by kableExtra, as the title suggests?

Comment: The background of the whole html object.